Nextjs Chunk Error for Dynamic Route in Build/Production Mode in Cpanel Apache (Hosting)
**I have Frontend App Deployed in Hosting using Cpanel Apache. I use port forwarding using .htaccess so in domain can access the port of Nextjs Server. **
All Page using Dynamic Route will occure chunk error
Here my .htaccess config
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
DirectoryIndex
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# Simple URL redirect:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:30000/$1 [P]
</IfModule>

The error only occure in Server. I already test the production/builded Next js App in Ubuntu and Windows and Work without problem
Here the screenshot of Chunk Error

This problem only occure in Production Server (Cpanel Apache Hosting).
I'm use App Route and Next V.14.2.14. I dont know what cause this problem
Is it from Apache server? or the Nextjs that incompatible with Apache?
Here in Local using Ubuntu and Windows. Nextjs app already use backend from production mode/server so its safe from backend problem


Fix The Chunck Error in Dynamic Route
